# What is difference between POST-request of Vert.x and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, post, vert.x

I have vert.x application. In my verticle I have such route to perform post-request:

```
router.post("/api/1").handler(routingContext -> {
            HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
            response
                    .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
                    .end("Response from api");
        });
```

OK, I want to test this request.

To do this I created unit-test:

```
@Test
    public void testApi1(TestContext context) {
        Async async = context.async();
        HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();
        HttpClientRequest request = client.post(8080, "localhost", "api/1", response -> {

            System.out.println("Some callback " + response.statusCode());
            async.complete();

        });
        String body = "{'username':'www','password':'www'}";
        request.putHeader("content-length", "1000");
        request.putHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.write(body);
        request.end();
    }
```

But when I try to execute this test I always get 404-error. In order to define the reason of this I used Postman (REST-client). It uses the follow request:

```
POST /api/1 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 6065383d-8f51-405c-08fd-9cc824a22f92
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

And this request return 404 too.

Very strange.

So I decided to create simple post-request from JavaScript - I used extremely simple code form JQuery:

```
$.post("/api/1");
```

And it returns me correct string, which I expect.

Who can explain me difference between these three issues.

Comment: Not sure about the Postman problem. But I think you missed a "/" in your test, it should be "/api/1"

Comment: I'm extremely stupid. Thank you very much. I'm ready to vote your answer if you add it as answer.

Comment: I'll add an answer in a minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your 
`HttpClientRequest request = client.post(8080, "localhost", "api/1", response -> {
...`

You missed a "/" in the beginning, it should be:

`HttpClientRequest request = client.post(8080, "localhost", "/api/1", response -> {
...`